# Windows 10 notifcation icon showing for .5 seconds

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

I continously have a sound for something going on, and then going off again half a second later in Windows 10. Looking at the notification icons, I see an icon popping in and out every 5-10 seconds. However, it's so quick I can never tell what it is.

This notification sound goes of continously, all the time my pc is on. I have tried looking through the logs, but not sure where to look. I would assume that something somewhere would show me the log about what the cause of the sound is.

Where can I get a better view of what is going on in my system. What notification icon is coming and going so quickly I cannot determine what it is.